# How to create nested tuplets in MuseScore

Tags: piano, composition, sheet-music, musescore, tuplet

[image]

When I created nested tuplets in Musescore, there was always a connected line between notes that I couldn't delete. How can I do to remove them.
(Redundant lines are underlined in red in the detached image).

Your help means so much to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Beam Symbols in the Beam Properties section of your workspace? I believe the upper rightmost of those Beam Symbols should do what you desire (as long as you successfully drag that symbol there). See https://musescore.org/en/handbook/beams for more details and for pictures of the Beam Symbols.